# Laravel-echo-server connection refused on first request

Tags: socket.io, laravel-5.4, laravel-echo

I have a problem with laravel-echo-server. When I load my site the first request over myapp.dev/socket.io/ fails with the error net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

After this request follow 3 more and these pass. If i try to send the same request that fails via curl it passes and on my local machine everything works fine.

Any ideas what it could be?